# Excel 2016 search mask

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have a load of data (40k rows +) in an Excel sheet and am trying to filter out all cells containing only two letters followed by two numbers. Can this be done?
All online resources I've seen so far so not touch on this, only how to perform simple searches.

Comment: There is no regex support in Excel, so you'd need to either use a macro or copy the data out into something like notepad++ and paste it back in once you've run your regex on it

Comment: https://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/